# Trigger click event on jqGrid cell editor

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with cell editing enabled.

I also have a delegated `click` event for all `<input>` elements. This means that when the user clicks on an `<input>` an on-screen keyboard is displayed so that they can edit the value (this solution is for a touch screen).

When the user clicks on a cell to initiate editing, the cell editor is displayed. However, the user then has to directly click on the cell editor to trigger the `click` event and display the on-screen keyboard (effectively having to 'double click' to edit the value).

**I want a way to be able to trigger the `click` event of the cell editor as soon as the editing starts.**

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#myGrid').jqGrid({
    // ...
    afterEditCell: function() {
        $(document.activeElement).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by doing the following.

First, I set the following:

```
$('#myGrid').jqGrid({
    //....
    cmTemplate: { editoptions: {class: 'jqg-editor'} }
    //....
});
```

This makes sure that the cell editor that is created by jqGrid automatically has the `jqg-editor` CSS class applied to it. So we can target it using a delegated 'on focus' event, like so:

```
$(document).on('focus.jqg', '.jqg-editor', function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

guys!
I do like the idea of @FixMaker, Thks! And I show below what I've done.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '#grupo_pesquisadores input', function() {
             $(this).trigger('click');

             if ($(this).attr("class") == 'fileIndividual') {
                  if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
                            $("#grupo_pesquisadores").find(".fileShared").prop("checked", false);
                  }
             }
             if ($(this).attr("class") == 'fileShared') {
                  if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
                            $("#grupo_pesquisadores").find(".fileIndividual").prop("checked", false);
                  }
             }
        });

   }); //document.ready end
```

I used it to control some checkboxes that I have. When I click on 'fileIndividual' checkbox it uncheck all checked 'fileShared' checkboxes, and if I click in any 'fileShared' checkbox it uncheck the 'fileIndividual' checkebox checked.